# How to calculate the sum of all the possible answers in a single-choice questionnaire?

Tags: weighted-data

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but imagine there are a number of single-choice questions with each answer having a numeric value (weight) assigned to it.

For example:

```
Q1 - question 1?
- answer a1 (10)
- answer b1 (20)
- answer c1 (0)

Q2 - question 2?
- answer a2 (30)
- answer b2 (-10)
.
.
.
Qn - question N?
- answer aN (20)
- answer bN (10)
```

Now I need a formula/equation or possibly an online tool that gives me the sum of all the weights users may choose as their answer.

I'm not really a data scientist but I know computer programming so please in simple terms.